# node.js googleapis library cannot find module '/node_modules/googleapis/apis/youtube/v3'

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, mithril.js

I'm using the the official Google Apis node.js library to fetch YouTube user info. I already have this working fine in another project, but for some reason I'm getting a strange error in this one. The goal is to fetch a list of videos scoped to a particular playlist id.

I'm using Mithril.js with coffeescript. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
google = require 'googleapis'

Properties.controller = (options = {}) ->
    @showVideos = (playlistId) =>
        youtube = google.youtube('v3')
        youtube.playlistItems.list({part:'snippet', playlistId: playlistId}).then(videos) ->
          console.log videos
```

The google client loads fine, but on this line:

```
youtube = google.youtube('v3')
```

I get the following error:

**Uncaught Error: Unable to load endpoint youtube("v3"): Cannot find module '/node_modules/googleapis/apis/youtube/v3'**

I use this exact same code in another project on the same computer in a neighboring directory. They are both using the same version of googleapis (I copied the working folder to this project just to be doubly sure).

I tried doing this with some of the other client endpoints such as with the [usage examples](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). None of them work. So it must be some kind of path variable?

Comment: a good thing to try when NPM can't find something is: `rm -rf node_modules; npm cache clean; npm install`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: my only other idea is to manually look through the path variables for something relevant. `console.log(process.env)`